# Cartthrob pro-rata subscriptions

Tags: cartthrob

I have a client that wishes to use the cartthrob subscriptions system in a slightly different manner.

Is it possible to have an annual payment at the start of the year and then if someone joins midway through the year for the first payment to be a 'pro-rata' version of the annual total?

So if the annual membership is £300 and a new customer signs up in June, they pay £150 for the first year and then £300 in January, the following year.

Thanks for your help,

Martyn

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create 2 different products: One that has no start date (starts immediately) with a  trial price of $150 and a standard price of $300. The other product would have no trial price and would have a start_date set for the next calendar year.

Another possible solution could be to simply add a trial price to the subscription product as soon as you are "into" the year of $150, and keep the standard price at $300.

Feel free to schedule a Phone/Skype appointment with the CartThrob/Mightybigrobot support team at http://support.mightybigrobot.com. A member of our support team can speak with your personally and will custom tailor a suitable solution to this issue if you think it needs further discussion.